Can a variable from the server be used for the "selected" default value in the SelectInput() function?
I am trying to use a numerical variable from the server as the default value for the "selectInput()" box in Shiny to no avail. There are two selection boxes, the first one is fixed, but I want the default value for the second one to be set by a variable, how can I achieve this? I tried using renderUI() and uniOutput() in different ways with no success.
library(shiny) 

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("year22"),
  selectInput("y1", label = "Start Year: ", choices = c(1900: 2024), 
              width = 100, size = 3, selectize = FALSE),
  selectInput("y2", label = "End Year: ", choices = c(1900: 2024),
              width = 100, size = 3, selected = year22, selectize = FALSE))

server <- function (input, output, session) {
    output$year22 <- renderUI({
      1963 #For simplicity I just included a number here instead of code, but I would 
           #like to use the variable 'year22' for the default value in the second 
           #selection box above
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)


Depending on your use case you can use e.g. a reactive to store the value for year22, then use updateSelectInput and an observer to set the selected= value for the second selectInput:
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("y1",
    label = "Start Year: ", choices = c(1900:2024),
    width = 100, size = 3, selectize = FALSE
  ),
  selectInput("y2",
    label = "End Year: ", choices = c(1900:2024),
    width = 100, size = 3, selected = NULL, selectize = FALSE
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  year22 <- reactive({ 1963 })
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      inputId = "y2",
      selected = year22()
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7692


UPDATE I can't reproduce the issue you reported in your comments. In the code below I added a textOutput to the code which outputs the value selected in the second selectInput and which shows that the input$y2 contains the selected value and no reversion of the selected= value to 1963.
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("y1",
    label = "Start Year: ", choices = c(1900:2024),
    width = 100, size = 3, selectize = FALSE
  ),
  selectInput("y2",
    label = "End Year: ", choices = c(1900:2024),
    width = 100, size = 3, selected = NULL, selectize = FALSE
  ),
  textOutput(
    "end_year"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  year22 <- reactive({
    1963
  })
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      inputId = "y2",
      selected = year22()
    )
  })
  
  output$end_year <- renderText({
    input$y2
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)



Thank you, that works initially, however, the value year22 continues defaulting to 1963 in this case, and does not allow the user to select another value from the "End Year' selection box.

Could you clarify what you mean by "does not allow the user to select another value from the "End Year' selection box."? Of course can the user select any year from the y2 selectInput. And if you want the selected year to change depending on e.g. the start year selected then you can do that inside the reactive named year22.

Thank you very much for your reply Stefan. Yes, the user can select another year in the second box, but as soon as I do it, the new selected value reverts to the initial default value (1963), so it does not stay.

Can't reproduce your issue. See my update where I added a textOutput. Perhaps this helps to clarify what's the issue you encounter.

Stefan, your code works just fine. I found the issue: I was using the code snippet inside another output on the server side; once I placed it outside of it, it worked as intended :-). Thanks a lot for your valuable time and talented expertise! Stack overflow is amazing!
